# Nextjs: What the ~ means in route pathnames?

Tags: next.js

Quick question, I'd to know what the `~` sign means inside route pathnames in nextjs.

I just saw this:
[image]

After searching through the new router docs, I couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The operator ~ doesn't mean anything in route pathnames,  they probably use this as a convention for important routes or styling. You can see the patterns of routing in the Next.js docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing)